# Subida de post en lotes usando wp_ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Estoy creando una función que lea un xml el cual contiene agencias y dentro de cada agencia las propiedades, la funcion primero recorre las agencias y las sube al wordpress en su respectivo cpt y va agarrando las propiedades de cada agencia para colocarlas en un array aparte, este array solo tendra las propiedades, las cuales se iran recorriendo en batches de 100 para no saturar el servidor, una vez subida las 100 verifica si quedan mas propiedades por subir, si es asi entonces vuelve a llamar la funcion usando wp_remote_get, el problema es que esta llamada no esta funcionando, en su momento funcionaba pero ahora no, ya he probado haciendo una llamada a la funcionget_properties_artekasa() de forma normal pero no es efectivo, se termina cayendo antes de subir todo, usando wp_remote_get si funcionaba bien porque era en segundo plano, les dejo mi codigo resumido:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_properties_artekasa', 'get_properties_artekasa' );
function get_properties_artekasa() {
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file(ABSPATH . "inmuebles.xml");
    $properties_content = [];
    $batch_size = 500; // Tamaño del lote

    // Procesar las propiedades del lote leído
    foreach ($xml as $agency) {
        // Procesamiento de la agencia
        $agency_id = slugify(strval($agency['id']));
        $agency_email = strval($agency['email']);
        $agency_phone = strval($agency['phoneno']);
        
        // Formateando telefono
        if(strpos($agency_phone, ' ') !== false):

            // Convertir la cadena en un array separando por espacios en blanco
            $agency_phone = explode(" ", $agency_phone);
            $agency_phone = $agency_phone[0];

            // Serializar el array para almacenarlo en la base de datos
            $agency_phone = $agency_phone;
        // Subida de agencia...
        
        // Agregar el ID de la agencia a cada propiedad
        foreach ($properties->property as $property) :
            $property['agency_id'] = $agency_post_id;
            $property['agency_email'] = $agency_email;
            $property['agency_phone'] = $agency_phone;
            $properties_content[] = $property;
        endforeach;
    } // Fin foreach de agencias
    
    // Cargar propiedades en lotes
    $total_properties = count($properties_content);
    $last_processed_index = get_option('last_processed_index') ? : 0;
    $batch_properties = array_slice($properties_content, $last_processed_index, $batch_size);

    foreach ($batch_properties as $property) :

        // Subidas de propiedes
    
    endforeach; // Fin foreach de propiedades

    // Incrementar el contador de propiedades procesadas
    $properties_processed = $last_processed_index + count($batch_properties);
    update_option('last_processed_index', $properties_processed);

    verify_count_properties($properties_processed, $total_properties);
}

function verify_count_properties($properties_processed, $total_properties){
    // Verificar si quedan más propiedades por procesar
    if ($properties_processed < $total_properties) {
        // Todavía hay propiedades por procesar, enviar una respuesta JSON con la cantidad restante
        wp_remote_get( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_properties_artekasa'), [
          'blocking' => true, //Esto nos permite activar la funcion y dejarnos ir a otra pagina sin bloquearnos
          'sslverify' => true // Desactiva la verificacion del SSl.
        ]);
    }else{  
        // Restablecer el índice después de completar la subida de todas las propiedades
        update_option('last_processed_index', 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sabría decirte exactamente porque falla, pero anteriormente también me tope con un problema parecido, había que importar mas de 2mil posts de un sitio a otro, el problema es que tenia demasiados custom fields y la mayoría de plugins o no tenían soporte completo de los fields o directamente crasheaban por que eran muchos posts, al final cree mi propio sistema para poder importar todos los datos, como eran muchos sabia que el servidor no podria hacerlo de un solo, así que lo que hice fue subir uno a uno.

Te explico, mi solución fue crear un JSON con los 2mil posts, entonces con javascript extraigo todos esos posts, el resultado es un array con 2mil items, con un ciclo for recorro cada ítem y por cada item lo que hago es enviar una petición ajax, importar el ítem y retornar una respuesta, si la respuesta es correcta entonces ir al siguiente ítem, importarlo y así sucesivamente, use ajax y funciones asíncronas para importar todos los posts de uno en uno así el servidor no se rompe.

Por ejemplo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // El numero del post actual
    let current = 0;

    // Aqui estaba guardando todos los posts que extraia de un JSON
    let $posts = import_db.posts;

    // En este div mostraba el total de posts a importar
    jQuery( '#total' ).html( import_db.posts.length );

    /**
     * 
     * Funcion de importación
     * Esta función recibe un array que seria el post
     * Ahi van datos como el title, content, fields, etc.
     * 
     * */
    function readFile( $post ){

        /**
         * 
         * Aqui hago que retorne una promesa
         * 
         * */
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            
            /**
             * 
             * Importo el post usando ajax
             * 
             * */
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : import_db.url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action  : 'import_db_ajax',
                    post    : JSON.stringify( $post ),
                },
                success: function(result){
                    /**
                     * 
                     * Si la respuesta el correcta
                     * El post actual le sumo 1
                     * Si al inicio es 0 ahora es 1
                     * Si era 1 ahora es 2
                     * Y asi sucesivamente
                     * 
                     * */
                    current = current + 1;
                    console.log( result );
                    resolve(current);
                }
            }).fail(function(response){
                /**
                 * 
                 * Si lleva a fallar igual sumo 1 al contador
                 * Y muestro en consola el numero de post que fallo
                 * 
                 * */
                current = current + 1;
                console.log( 'Error in Post ' + current );
                resolve(current);
            });

        });

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Ahora creo una función asincrona
     * Esta funcion es la que recorre 
     * el array con los 2 mil posts
     * Al ser una función asincrona
     * Solo pasa el siguiente item
     * Cuando la promesa actual se resuelve
     * 
     * */
    async function readJsonFile() {
        
        for ( const $post of $posts ) {
            const contents = await readFile( $post );
            jQuery( '#current' ).html( contents );
        }
    
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Por ultimo, ejecuto esta función al dar click en un boton
     * 
     * */
    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#start', function(){
        readJsonFile();
    });

});
```

Así que basado en este ejemplo podrías hacer lo siguiente, extrae todas las agencias con javascript y guárdalas en una variable.

Luego recorre ese array de agencias, por cada array envías una petición ajax que subirá el post, tiene que ser una función asíncrona porque cada petición debe hacerse una a la vez, si envías 200 peticiones lo mas seguro es que el servidor no las soporte.

Para las propiedades podrías hacer algo parecido, lo recomendable seria hacer un array con todas tus agencias y dentro de cada agencia un array con cada propiedad.

Ahora lo que haces es importar cada agencia, una vez que la agencia esta creada retornas el id de la agencia y comienzas a importar las propiedades de esa agencias, cuando todas las propiedades estén importadas entonces pasas a la segunda agencia y así sucesivamente.

Espero que esto te de una idea de como solucionar tu problema.

Comment: con este metodo se puede llamar a traves de un cron en segundo plano?

Comment: el problema es que wp_remote_get no funciona y antes lo hacia, no se que me este faltando

Comment: No, esto no funciona con cron, ya que necesita el fronted para ejecutarse.

Comment: me imaginaba, ya he probado este tipo funciones pero aquí no me sirve, necesito algo que funcione en segundo plano con un cron

Comment: ya vi porque no servia el wp_remote_get, tengo que colocar ajuro la funcion para que pueda ser llamada por ajax sin auntenticarse

Comment: No hay problema, dejaré la respuesta, puede que le sirva a alguien en el futuro.